# CRM 2016 api calls not working when Business process is activated, works again after deactivating

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have an entity named medical case

It has 1:N relation with another entity named family

I have a subgrid in medical case where you can add families

So to fetch the list of families involved in medical case, I make the below api call

```
http://localhost/CRMSERVER/api/data/v8.0/new_medicalcase(bgcs0249-0a06-e611-941a-003002djlnc)?$expand=new_medical_new_family
```

This works fine when I don't activate the business process

But when I activate the business process, and refresh the page and refresh the api call, it gives the below error

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"Property 'stageid' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind. Entity new_pokagonchildwelfarecases has duplicate navigation property names. All property names (Navigation and Structural property) must be unique in an Entity ","innererror":{
      "message":"Property 'stageid' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind. Entity new_pokagonchildwelfarecases has duplicate navigation property names. All property names (Navigation and Structural property) must be unique in an Entity ","type":"Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataEntityTypeSerializer.CreateSelectExpandNode(EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteEntry(Object graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataEntityTypeSerializer
```

When I deactivate the business process flow, create a new record and try the api call for that entity by changing the id, it works fine. And it fails again if I activate the business process flow

Comment: Your query is retrieving all fields for both entities. Try modifying the query to request only one attribute from both entities...does the error still occur?

Comment: the query is not working even if i omit the $expand parameter
this happens if I activate the business process and create entity records

Comment: Ok you got rid of the expand, good.  Now add a select for some string field, like this: `http://localhost/CRMSERVER/api/data/v8.0/new_medicalcase(bgcs0249-0a06-e611-941a-003002djlnc)?$select=new_name`(assuming new_name is a string field). I'm guessing you'll still get the error, but it's worth trying just in case.

Comment: tried it, no luck @Polshgiant

Comment: Then you're most likely dealing with a platform bug. Quickest path to resolution will be to file a support request with Microsoft.